# Drupal7 user reset password link not working

Tags: theming

Hi i have created a custom hook in my own themeplate

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_pass'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-reset',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'mytheme_preprocess_user_pass'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

function mytheme_preprocess_user_pass(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my super awesome reg form');
}
```

This is the code in user-reset.tpl.php

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="yourtheme-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div>
```

after the user register. an activation link will send to the user email 
example: http://www.mysite.com/user/reset/98/1366527945/qr6sEqrJwpWjQ11sxQPpitIHosg3_-Iv1s08yrKlnYk

Problem is:

When user trying to click the link, the page give me an error "The page isn't redirecting properly"

is there anything i missed on my own theme?

cherrs

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with your custom code?

Comment: what is in user-reset.tpl.php and why is that the template name for the user_pass theme item?
Is your intro text actually displaying on the form and is the user_pass form displaying as it should?

Comment: <code> Hi this the code inside user-reset.tpl.php <p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="yourtheme-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div> </code> i just want to customize the message on the reset password page.. thanks

Comment: You can't put code in comments. Also, check the edit I made to your question, it has the correct syntax for code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what is wrong with your code (I will check it out in a min), but if the purpose is just to add some text to the password reset form, I would do it in one of these ways:

1. Add a custom block with the text you want to add and assign it to the user register page.
2. Add a custom module and use hook_form_alter to add custom markup. Like so:

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_user_pass_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['intro_text'] = array(
    '#markup' => '<p class="intro-text">' . t('This is my super awesome reg form') . '</p>',
    '#weight' => -10,
  );
}
```